# Select spans of set bits in a bitmask that overlap with a 1-bit in a selector bitmap

Tags: c++, x86, bit-manipulation, bmi

Given:

- A bitmask `a` (say, `std::uint64_t`), which contains at least one set (`1`) bit.
- A selector bitmask `b` which is a subset of `a` (i.e. `a & b == b`), and has at least one bit set.

I want to select spans of contiguous 1-bits in `a` which overlap with a bit in `b`:

```
a = 0b1111001110001100;
b = 0b0000001010001000;
//c=0b0000001110001100
//    XXXX  YYY   ZZ
```

The XXXX group is 0 in `c` because `b & XXXX` is false.  The ZZ group is copied because `b` has one of the Z bits set.  The YYY group is also set in `c` for the same reason.  **Notice that `b` can have multiple set bits in a single group in `a`**.

So for every contiguous group of `1`s in `a`, set all of those bits in `c` if `b` has a `1` in any of those positions.  A more complex example:

```
std::uint64_t a = 0b1101110110101;
std::uint64_t b = 0b0001010010001;
// desired   c == 0b0001110110001
// contiguous groups   ^^^ ^^   ^  that overlap with a 1 in b

assert(a & b == b);           // b is a subset of a

std::uint64_t c = some_magic_operation(a, b);
assert(c == 0b0001110110001);
```

Are there any bit-logic instructions/intrinsics (MMX, SSE, AVX, BMI1/BMI2), or bit manipulation tricks which allows me to calculate `c` from  `a` and `b` efficiently?  (i.e. without loops)?

---

ADDITIONAL:

Using hint from Denis' answer I can only imagine loop-based algorithm:

```
std::uint64_t a = 0b0110111001001101;
std::uint64_t b = 0b0100101000001101;
assert(a & b == b); // subset

std::cout << std::bitset< 16 >(a) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::bitset< 16 >(b) << std::endl;
std::uint64_t x = (a + b) & ~a;
std::uint64_t c = 0;
while ((x = (a & (x >> 1)))) { // length of longest 1-series times
    c |= x;
}
std::cout << std::bitset< 16 >(c) << std::endl;
```

Comment: does "a segment" include segments of length 1?

Comment: @M.M Yes, 1-segment is just non-zero-length sequence of 1-s.

Comment: It took me about 10 minutes to decode your description, so I made an edit to clarify for future readers.  I assume you left out Intel's BMI1/BMI2 extensions by accident, not because [Haswell is too new](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#Supporting_CPUs).  You did mention AVX, which is by no means baseline: not supported even on [Skylake Celeron/Pentium](http://ark.intel.com/products/90732), only i3 and higher.  Thanks, Intel :(

Comment: Actually, none of the BMI instructions are obviously useful on their own.  Possibly `pext` / `pdep` as building blocks, though.  Do you absolutely need the output in the format you specified?  Denis's answer loses the information about how big each group was, but does have a 1 in the result for each matching group.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for correction. I'm very grateful.

Comment: @PeterCordes I need a (selected) parts of mask. What format can can be helpful for someone you can propose?

Comment: What do you do with the resulting mask?  Is there a way you can modify the code/algorithm that uses the result, to allow a simpler calculation?  I don't have anything specific in mind, other than Denis's output format (`(a+b)&~a`).  If `b` only had a 1 in the low bit of a group, we could maybe do `( (a+b)&~a ) - b` so borrow would turn groups back into all-1s, stopping at the 1bit from Denis's expression.  Is there any chance you can arrange for `b` to have that extra condition?

Comment: @PeterCordes In my real case - no. Many bits of selector may "hit" particular 1-series of source bitmask.

Comment: @Orient: The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56467971/2439725) is probably a duplicate of your question. Nevertheless, you might be interested in my [SIMD optimized solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56478996/2439725).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of `uint64_t` you may do this trick:

Let's set `a = 0b11011101101`. Having at least one 0 bit is important. The bitmask has 4 separate areas, filled with 1 bits. If you do `c=a+(a&b)`, then each 1-filled area will overflow if at least one bit of `b` in this area is set. So you can check then, which area was overflown. For example, if you want 1-bits in 2-nd and 3-rd areas of `a`, you may do so:

```
    assert(c & 0b00100010000);
    //              ^^^ ^^ this segments overflows
```

Comment: In my real case MSB is zero. Nice.

Comment: explanation: `a&b == b`, so that step is redundant.  Masking with `& ~a` removes all bits other than the carries out of selected groups in `a`.